# Website order completion notify

Tags: php, email, communication, notify

I have a web application written in PHP with a MySQL database for designing a kitchen and ordering the units. When a customer completes their design, they will then pay. From this, I need a sure-fire way to notify the systems at the factory to retrieve the job information on from the remote database and begin processing the job, eg creating machine instructions, printing out reports, submitting the information to the accountancy package. I have begun work on the receiving system in Go.

My question is, what is the best way for the remote PHP application to notify the factory-side Go application that a new order has been placed and paid for? Should I use email and have the application pick it up, or is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: Does the factory has own webpage? is your page and factory's on the same domain?

Comment: It's hard to tell which way would be the best. It depends on your IT infrastructure, on what you GO system is able to do (I don't know what it is actually), and also on your desired process (I mean, probably the factory doesn't need a real-time notification...)

Comment: @Sergio, The web application is on the factory's domain. However, it's a remote server, away from the factory. I need to be able to notify the system at the physical factory somehow.

Comment: @Bartdude, Go is a programming language. I have begun programming a system to receive notifications from the PHP application, and to then do with it the relevant tasks that I need.

Comment: email to the factories general email sounds easiest for me... do you know ho to do it? (it can have a link to your page so they confirm they read it, otherwise the mail sends again by "cron")

Comment: @Sergio, that seems all too manual. I want the systems to talk to each other more effectively than using email.

Comment: I was thinking that TCP/IP sockets would be the best way to go.